# Merging result from $query->result() and an array codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have an sql query which returns values. I would want to add new values with keys so that I can use it to my next controller which is these values doesn't come from the query result.

My Model:

```
$paymentDetails = $this->db->query($sql);
$payments = $paymentDetails->result();

//these are the values I wanted to add to the result for the $payments
$amountDue = 'Sample';
$change = 'Sample';

$result = array_merge($payments,  array(
                "AmountDue" => $amountDue,
                "Change" => $change
            ));
if($result){
    return $result;
}else{
    return false;
}
```

I wonder why array_merge() doesn't work. In my view, values fetched from the SQL Query did returned, but the added (AmountDue and Change) is not found.

Please help me. Thank you so much! Ya'll be a big help for my project. :)

Comment: write a debug command print_r($payments); exit; after your second line and show us the result.

Comment: Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [PaymentId] => 63 [AmountPaid] => 5000.00 [SalesInvoiceNo] => 9 [PaymentDate] => 2015-01-14 18:48:04 [PaymentName] => Reservation Fee [ModeName] => Cash [LastName] => Estrada [FirstName] => Christoeffer John [MiddleName] => Restauro ) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because result() function returns the query result as an array of objects, or an empty array on failure. It is just an alias of result_object().

You have to use result_array() which returns the query result as a pure array.

I hope this will help you.